# Drawing image in a .Maui Map Control

Tags: c#, dictionary, maui

My project requires displaying an image in a specific region of a map, very similar to the built-in Polygon function (but always a rectangular area), but with an image filling the area rather than color. Is there any way to achieve this?

I considered changing the opacity property of map control to overlay an image, but it was definitely a very bad approach. Please advice.

Comment: I've done something similar in the past by layering a transparent canvas on top of the map

Comment: At least in Maui maps, this is a very bad idea. Not only managing geo cordinates for the image is impossible (consider the complicated touch operations that can happen on the map layer), also, I need the image to completely cover part of the original map without affecting other elements such as pin/polygon/polyline.

Comment: I didn't say it was a great idea, but it can be made to work.  Fundamentally the built in Map control is pretty basic and if you have more complex requirements you need to use a different control

Comment: Someone raised the same issue in GitHub ([Add custom pin image/icon functionality for Maps #10400](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10400)), you can follow it